# Overriding preceding function in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, overriding, fade

Say I have many div "pages" set up like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$('.link').on('click', function(e){
    fadeOutPage();
    $(this.getAttribute("href")).fadeIn(); //fade in clicked page
});

function fadeOutPage() {
    $('#container>div').fadeOut(); //fade out all displayed pages
}

</script>

<a href="#page1" class="link">page 1</a>
<a href="#page2" class="link">page 2</a>
<a href="#page3" class="link">page 3</a>

.... 
....

<div id="container">

    <div id="page1">
        <div class="navbar"> contents of navbar 1 </div>
        <div class="pagecontents"> contents of page 1 </div>
        <div class="pagefooter"> more contents for page 1 </div>
    </div>

    <div id="page2">
        <div class="navbar"> contents of navbar 2 </div>
        <div class="pagecontents"> contents of page 2 </div>
        <div class="pagefooter"> more contents for page 2 </div>
    </div>

    <div id="page3">
        <div class="navbar"> contents of navbar 3 </div>
        <div class="pagecontents"> contents of page 3 </div>
        <div class="pagefooter"> more contents for page 3 </div>
    </div>

    ...
    ...

</div>
```

This works as I intend it, fade out all pages then fade in the clicked page when I click a link. **But I want to delay the fade in of ".pagefooter"**, for let's say 1000ms, but keep ".pagefooter" inside the parent div "#pageX". Right now when I call "$(this.getAttribute("href")).fadeIn();" it will fade in "#pageX" all at the same time.

How do I override that so I can insert a settimeout(function() {('.pagefooter').fadeIn()},1000) somewhere, so that everything else except ".pagefooter" fades in normally, then ".pagefooter" fades in 1000ms afterwards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**: Here you go:

```
$('#page1').show().find('div').hide().filter(function () {
    return !$(this).hasClass('pagefooter');
}).fadeIn().add('.pagefooter').delay(1000).fadeIn();
```

Here's a working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mFjg5/1

Comment: You might not have read my question clearly. I don't want to delay the whole thing, I want to delay the fading in of one div only within the parent div.

Comment: I believe your function checks if the link has the class "pagefooter" appended to it. But I need it to check if the "#pageX" has a child div called ".pagefooter", not the link

Comment: Thanks but that seems to be only applicable to "#page1". I've got about 30 pages though, all named in the "#pageX" format. The function I have for fading in/out pages is universal for all pages.

Comment: Ya use your old syntax `$(this.getAttribute("href"))`, this is just an example to show the desired result on jsfiddle.

Comment: Thanks that edited version worked. But can you explain the logic in the code? I don't quite follow it. It's causing some weird bugs with certain hide/show elements in my other pages. For example I have an FAQ page with hide/show question/answer text blocks. With this code the question/answer text blocks keep flashing between hide and show.

Comment: You could change `find()` to `children()` if nested divs are getting screwed up. The logic reads like a book - Selects the container, shows it, then hides all divs inside it except those which have the class pagefooter. Then it fades them in, then selects that pagefooter child and waits one second, and fades it in.